# Gnome 3: проблемы в панели сверху

Tags: gnome

У меня такая проблема. Если у меня запущено много индикаторов в панели сверху, то становится не видно часы, раскладку клавиатуры и т.п: вместо них отображается троеточие.Примерно вот так:![экран][1]Как это можно исправить? (знаю, это некритично, но неудобно, что часов не видно)ОС - Linux Mint 12  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGCFi.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

установите дополнение, а потом включите его: Extend left box (https://extensions.gnome.org)